# CNN model accuracy

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm beginner to python CNN models and I've build a model to classify ASL alphabet letters based on the data set in this link https://www.kaggle.com/grassknoted/asl-alphabet with 95% accuracy. However, I got another data set to evaluate the model from this link https://www.kaggle.com/danrasband/asl-alphabet-test and there was a huge drop in the accuracy, it was 45% accuracy I got from the built-in evaluate function. So, is this an over-fitting problem or there is some thing wrong in the code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
#from keras import utils
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from math import ceil
import numpy as np
import os
#import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

class Model:

  classifier = None
  def __init__(self, Type):
    self.classifier = Type
    
  
  def build_model(classifier, choose_model):
    
    if choose_model == 1:
      classifier.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 1), activation='relu'))
      #classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      
      classifier.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

    elif choose_model == 2:
      classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 1), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      
      classifier.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      #classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
      
      classifier.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
    elif choose_model == 3:
      classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(64, 64, 1), activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
      classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

      classifier.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
      classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

      

    classifier.add(Flatten())

    #classifier.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

    classifier.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))


    classifier.add(Dense(15, activation='softmax'))

    return classifier

  def save_classifier(path, classifier):
    classifier.save(path)

  def load_classifier(path):
    classifier = load_model(path)
    return classifier

  def predict(classess, classifier, img):
    pred = classifier.predict(img)
    print(classes[np.argmax(pred)])

class DataGatherer:

  def __init__(self, dir):
    self.dir = dir

  #the below 3 variabels are for data(image) augmentation
  data_gen = None
  train_data_gen = None
  test_data_gen = None


  #this function does not augment the images
  def load_images(self):
    images = []
    labels = []
    index = -1

    for folder in os.listdir(self.dir):
      index += 1
      counter = 0
      print("Loading images from folder ", folder ," has started.")
      for image in os.listdir(self.dir + '/' + folder):
        if (counter % 500) == 0:
          print(counter, " images has been loaded from folder ", folder)
        

        #img = cv2.imread(self.dir + '/' + folder + '/' + image, 0)
        #img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
        img = load_img(self.dir + '/' + folder + '/' + image, target_size=(64, 64), color_mode='grayscale')
        img = img_to_array(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

        images.append(img)
        labels.append(index)
        
        counter += 1
      print("Loading images from folder ", folder ," has finished.")
      #cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    images = np.array(images)
    labels = utils.to_categorical(labels)

    print("Converting numerical labels to categorical has finished")

    #x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.1)
    #print("Spliting data has finished")

    return images, labels

training_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/asl alphapet/asl_alphapet_train/half_data'
validate_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/asl alphapet/asl_alphabet_validate'

batch_size = 64
training_size = 40500
test_size = 4500

compute_steps_per_epoch = lambda x: int(ceil(1. * x/batch_size))
steps_per_epoch = compute_steps_per_epoch(training_size)
val_steps = compute_steps_per_epoch(test_size)

data_gatherer = DataGatherer(training_dir)

data_gatherer.data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        #rotation_range=20,
        validation_split=0.1
        )

data_gatherer.train_data_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        training_dir,
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True, seed=42,
        subset='training',
        color_mode='grayscale')
data_gatherer.test_data_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        training_dir,
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True, seed=42,
        subset='validation',
        color_mode='grayscale')

classifier = Model.load_classifier("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/alphapet_classifiers/15_litters_classifier.h5")

classifier.evaluate(data_gatherer.test_data_gen)

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validate_data = data_gen.flow_from_directory(validate_dir, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=batch_size, target_size=(64, 64))

classifier.evaluate(validate_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the original dataset is a Black-White dataset, which is what your model is built for, but the second dataset is an RGB one, also, there is a lot of noise on RGB images, like the ones on the second dataset, so that might also affect your final validation accuracy.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Also I doubt this should be a question of SO it more of the question of this instead https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've converted both of them to grayscale. However, aside from the color issue, I've looked in the code section in the second link and found that they have the same problem too and found out that real-world images need further preprocessing before prediction process.